# Actual and expected string has same result but still the test fails say expected [true] but found [false]

Tags: java, string, selenium-webdriver

I have expected and actual string they seem match but the test fails not sure what is missing.

```
driver.get("url");
String actualString = driver.findElement(By.id("label1")).getText();
System.out.println(actualString);
String expectedString = "{USER1}OK;\r\n" + 
            "{USER2}OK; ";

System.out.println(expectedString);
assertTrue(actualString.equals(expectedString));
```

This is HTML

```
<span id="label" class="error" style="display:inline-block;width:600px;">
{USER1}OK;
 <br>
 {USER2}OK;
 </span>
```

The actual string i'm getting from println is like below

```
{USER1}OK;
{USER2}OK;
```

The expected is also same from println but still it fails

Comment: Any tailing whitespace? Try using the `trim()` method: `actualString.trim().equals(expectedString.trim())`. You definitely have a trailing whitespace in `expectedString`. Is that on purpose?

Comment: Highlight the two `String`'s. One has a space at the end and one doesn't

Answer (score 2):

### @GBlodgett is correct.

Generally, by default, `.getText()` will automatically perform a trim. Some browsers *cough* don't, so be aware.

So you are comparing a trimmed String to a String with a forced space at the end, thus, will consistently fail.

Comment: Nice explanation (+1) . Any reference for `.getText()` will automatically perform a trim?

Comment: @DebanjanB yes; per the spec, .getText() *should* automatically trim the text captured. However I know that at least Edge has a known bug that it doesn’t trim. So for cross-browser support you should always manually trim captured text. Especially if you’re going to do a comparison

Comment: @MivaScott Yes, you mentioned in your answer _`.getText()` should automatically trim the text captured_. Didn't find anything concrete about it in the [documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getText--) Wanted to know if you are aware about the source code.

Comment: Thanks for info abt edge. But what if the actual has dynamic value. Can we compare and how

Comment: @John, use `actualString.trim().equals(expectedString.trim())`